# Are there any Marvel characters who can instantly heal others from injuries?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Who aren't also mutants, massively powerful mages, or cosmic entities?

Comment: "Are there any Marvel characters who can heal?" Pretty much all creatures can heal. Do you mean they heal instantaneously or rapidly or from close to death or are healers for others or what? Humans (even in the Marvel Universe) heal all the time. That's why not every cut leads to bleeding to death. **Please clarify.**

Comment: @Thaddeus Are you sure your edit is what the question was asking? It makes sense, but there is doubt given characters like Wolverine.

Comment: The question is asking about people who can HEAL others, NOT REGENERATE themselves. It is the nature of the question that reveals what the person is asking. Only mutants, mages and cosmic-level beings possess healing powers as a rule. I believe the OP wanted to know if there were any exceptions to that general Marvel trope. It is a fair question, especially given the number of heroes in the MU, there are very few acknowledged healers...

Comment: @Thaddeus is right. I worded it poorly but he's right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean characters who possess the power to heal the injuries of others, at an accelerated rate; there are curiously, once you eliminate mutants, mages or cosmic-level beings, few mutate or non-mutant healers in the canon Marvel Earth-616 continuity. Regenerative abilities are far more common.

- [The Black Tarantula](http://marvel.com/universe/Black_Tarantula) is the rare exception in that we know his power is passed down generationally, but not attributed to mutation. It might be possible for it to be magical but he is not normally seen using magical abilities as a mage might.

[image]

Martin Li ([Mister Negative](http://marvel.wikia.com/Mister_Negative_%28Earth-616%29)) had the power to heal even before augmenting it with the Darkforce (an energy whose origins are still relatively unexamined) and could use it to heal cancer or speed healing.

- The few healers who do exist are almost always plot devices or providing a means for characters to recover from injuries faster than they would normally such as [Sister Salvation](http://marvel.wikia.com/Sister_Salvation_%28Earth-616%29), a healer who the source of her powers is as yet, unknown.
- The most other healers are often mutants such as the [Healer of the Morlocks](http://marvel.wikia.com/Healer_%28Earth-616%29). The Morlocks were a large community of mutants who felt they were outcasts, living in the underground tunnels beneath New York, New Jersey, and Connecticut and were destroyed by the Marauders in a mutant massacre. Occasionally, they are mages such as Doctor Strange or the lesser known [Wiccan](http://marvel.wikia.com/William_Kaplan_%28Earth-616%29) of the Young Avengers.

A list of all Marvel's well known healers can be found [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/Category:Healers). This list is not all-inclusive, since it does not list every member of most of the largest pantheons who possess the power of healing along with a litany of other abilities.